# Enabling Text selection in Extjs tab

Tags: extjs

In my page I'm creating tabPanels using exjs 4.1.3. problem is I'm not able select text of tab title using mouse.

here is my code:

```
TabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'tabs',
        resizeTabs: true,
        enableTabScroll: true,
        width: 'auto',
        border:false,
        plain: true,
        tabBar: {
            layout: {
                scrollIncrement: 100
            },
            height: 24,          
            defaults: {
                height: 24           
            }
        },
        items: [{
            title: listTabLabel,
            id: 'firstTab',
            border:false,
            items:mainPanel,
            closable: false,
            tabConfig:{
                style: {
                    borderRadius: 0,
                },
                margin: '0 0 0 0'
            }
        }]
})
```

as I open a new tab i call this below code to add new tab

```
TabPanel.add({
    id: record,
    closable: true,
    html: tabContent,
    title: name,     
    tooltip: tabName,
    dirty: false,
    recordValue: ''+record,
    height:50,
    tabConfig: {
        style: {
            borderRadius: 0
        },
        margin: '0 0 0 -2'              
    } 
}
```

What I have tried:
I used Extjs selectable function as below

```
listeners : {
    boxready: function() {
        Ext.select('.x-tab-center').selectable();  /*To enable user selection of text*/
    }
}
```

it enables the text selection but it is not smooth enough. 
issues:
1. text will not be selected if i drag the mouse on the text, i must drag the mouse from outside.
2. selection is not happening if select it from middle. ex: if my tab name is ABCDFE, then I'm not able to select only dfe.

Please help to solve this issue. 
here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tnh)

Comment: Can you please create some fiddle and show this example in it.I will fix this  issue there itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response @tejas1991. In fiddle it works fyn :( we noticed the problem is button. In above code while creating tab title it uses button tag. So if I use selectable () if I keep the courser outside the button tag and Trag the text will b selectable. But not inside the button.

Comment: I just checked your fiddle as you say we  for tab title extjs uses button tag .For curiosity I changed name of button tag to label,and it worked fine(with functionality).So we need one way where we can replace this button tag by label tag.

Comment: yea current fix is i changed the button to div. it works smoothly. but manipulating DOM is not that good idea right so trying other workaround.

Comment: its ok to manipulate DOM until & unless its functionality is not going to change.i dont think it will produce any wrong results.I think label is good instead of div if we are replacing for tag name.

Comment: why label is better than div? i checked with label too i didnot feel any difference. can you explain me pleas.

Comment: Thats ok if you use label,div,span or any other thing. But tell one thing if you have already achieved selection thing( leaving some problems like selecting text in middle) then can you tell me your requirement so that I can suggest you which component you can use.

Comment: I achieved selection just using selectable. But to make it smooth enough I replaced button with div.

Comment: my requirement is make the text selection smoothly. like how we do normal text select in a text file.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to 4.2?  If so, the issue goes away as the tab no longer uses a Button.  [See Fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1u66).

Comment: sadly i cant do that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved by manipulating DOM

```
          boxready: function() {
                Ext.select('.x-box-inner, .x-tab-center').selectable();
                var idVal = this.tab.btnEl.id;
                var button = document.getElementById(idVal);
                var height = button.style.height;
                var divEl = Ext.DomHelper.insertBefore(button, {       /*added a div in replacement of button*/
                    tag: 'div', 
                    id : idVal,
                    cls: 'RF_tabHeader x-tab-center',
                    title: button.title,
                    style: 'height: '+height
                });

                divEl.update(button.innerHTML);
                button.parentNode.removeChild(button);                 /* button tag is removed.*/
            }
```